# Can I set up a Dell PowerEdge Server without Monitor and Keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, home-server, setup

I have just got my Dell PowerEdge 2950. I have inserted new hard drives et cetera.

Is it possible for me to install an OS without needing to buy a monitor or keyboard?
I thought the server can be completely managed remotely. Is it?

Answer (score 4):

Servers are generally managed headless (remotely), but only *after* they've first been set up. The normal practice is to connect them to a mouse, keyboard and monitor (possibly via kvm) while the initial setup and installation is performed, and then remove those items when the server is put into production.

So, if you have an existing desktop machine from which you can (temporily) disconnect your monitor, that's what you'll need to do. If you don't have a monitor you can borrow, most recent TVs will support PC connections with the right cable (which will be much cheaper than buying a whole new display).

Another option is an IP KVM. This is a device that connects to your server and presents a keyboard, mouse, and display to it, but rather than connecting to a real keyboard, mouse, and display, set's up a service that you can connect to over the network to control the server. Unfortunately, the price is likely higher than just buying a display, keyboard, and mouse.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, It is possible.  You will have to plug in the DRAC Interface, and connect to it using a web browser on another machine.

You would do that from a PC that's on the same network as that DRAC interface.  The DRAC NIC has a default IP address of 192.168.0.120, Gateway 192.168.0.1 and mask of 255.255.255.0
Once connected to that address, the username Root, password Calvin should work, if the settings are fresh.

Once in, you should be able to do whatever you need using the Console

If that IP doesn't come up for you, grab a free net scanning tool off the web and just look for a new address on your network.

Answer (score 0):

Possible but given the cost of a keyboard and mouse, it would be a bit easier if you had them.  Once set up, the keyboard and mouse are not needed if you use a remote tool like RDP or the DRAC.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to access it remotely. According to this page about the [Dell 2950](http://www.servermonkey.com/dell-poweredge-2950/), it has an integrated intelligent platform management interface 2.0 management controller, with an ***optional*** DRAC 5 remote management card. As Kirk mentioned in a response above, you'll need to plugin the DRAC Interface, and connect to it using a web browser on another machine.

But to be honest, it'll be a lot easier to just use a mouse and keyboard. They are extremely cheap these days anyways.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[As per the fine manual](https://downloads.dell.com/manuals/all-products/esuprt_ser_stor_net/esuprt_poweredge/poweredge-2950_setup%20guide_en-us.pdf) there's VGA, and USB ports at the back you can use. They *are* at the back so a little tricky once its in the rack.

There were also rackmount KVM setups with a built in monitor that were often used with these. Some other models also had these ports *in front*